# Laravel CsrfToken expires on refresh after switching servers

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I know my issue is not because of Laravel but most likely the php configuration (sessions), but I am not sure what to check. I was running this particular project on a `homestead` and it was fine. Now after I submit a form (it's a steps controller, `post` form -> go to step 2 etc.) and refresh the page my csrf token is invalid.

I thought it was because of session lifetime and such or generation of new token, but no .. the token is the same, but I still get `TokenMismatchException` after I refresh the page.

The environment is pretty much the same as the homestead (nginx (latest), php(5.6, I don't know what homestead had) ). The logins work fine, I stay logged in while browsing, but when I go through the steps this happens ..

**Problem & Solution:**

As per comments bellow where I forgot to update, I found out the problem was actually the fact, that the dev server was forced through cloudflare, but the base url in Laravel was left at `http://...` - I just added to `AppServiceProvider`

```
$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
```

and it wasn't doing the verification error.

Comment: Have you correctly set up .env file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments bellow where I forgot to update, I found out the problem was actually the fact, that the dev server was forced through cloudflare, but the base url in Laravel was left at `http://...` - I just added to `AppServiceProvider`

```
 $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
```

and it wasn't doing the verification error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you send a csrf token with the form you submit? If not: how did you build up your form, with FormBuilder or Html?

**FormBuilder**

In the formbuilder the CSRF token is already posted so it's not needed to send it.

**Html**

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    {{ csrf_field() }} //This is what you need!
    ...
</form>
```

You did not provide an error log, check in your laravel project for storage/logs and then provide us the error so we can help you.

Comment: There is nothing in the logs and it is using the the html one. I don't get why it is like that. Basicly it's just a simple form with 2 hidden inputs and csrf_field using `post` that leads you to `/setup/step-2` from `/setup` but when I refresh instantly the `/setup/step-2` there it is the `TokenMismatchException`

Comment: Is the data being posted inside the database or where ever you're posting your data to? Or does that also not happen. Because you talk about refreshing, so it might be that it posts and then kills a session.

*Are you using a adblocker? Have you tried this with multiple browsers or only 1?

Comment: It is a split form it just posts to the next page filling few hidden fields.  The adblocker doesn't seem to change anything I mean it's not in the code since it's been working with homestead I am just not sure what breaks it on the new server.

Comment: I had the exact same problem while running adblocker on google chrome, it broke of sessions, which is why the token was renewed and I got back a TokenMismatchException a dozen times. I know you 'just switched servers', but now you're having trouble so it's worth a thing to go and check every possible outcome there is to fix this problem. What does it do when you use it in incognito in chrome? Or another browser? And to be clear: the form just submits values to another form? is that correct?

Comment: Okay I figured it out. It was due the use of https on the subdomain I created for testing some APIs. It had cloudflare's SSL, but despite the fact that I had app url set to `https://..****` all routes still lead to `http://...****`. After quick search I used `$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);` in my `AppServiceProvider` to force the use of https and now it's all good.

Comment: @JustDeveloper use Strict SSL in cloudflare. You will not need this line anymore after that.